# Failed an audit because I flagged as duplicate when it really is one

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, specific-audit

I just [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/33219815) because I flagged a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74220927/using-awk-to-only-include-column-beginning-with-specific-value) as duplicate.
The question has a comment to the same effect that links to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213292/how-to-use-awk-to-filter-column-so-it-begins-with-specific-value) that is the same almost verbatim (ending in `.` instead of `?`). Yet neither is marked as a duplicate of
the other.

I stand by my decision to flag as duplicate on the [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74220927/using-awk-to-only-include-column-beginning-with-specific-value) I was presented with, as both have a good answer but the [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74213292/how-to-use-awk-to-filter-column-so-it-begins-with-specific-value) was created earlier.

Comment: Yeah uh, that's pretty obviously a bad audit.  The questions should really be merged at this point.

Comment: So you failed the audit, which was obviously an audit, since it indicate that a perfectly valid question was "possible spam".  So did you outside of the audit flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: The two questions are posted by the same person.  They shouldn't be duplicates, one of them should be deleted.  Or both of them since the user posted the second one while the first one was locked, per comments....

Comment: @DanielWiddis • There's nothing wrong with closing one question as duplicate of another question posted by the same author. In fact that's what is used to handle OP re-posting questions, suggested by the fact that it's not possible to close as duplicate if the target has no answer **unless the questions are posted by the same author**. ■ By the way, the second one is posted while the first one was **put on hold**, not locked, per the post timeline. ■

Comment: Remark, it seems a bit unlikely odd that the second question gets an overwhelming positive response (+6) for it to be made into an audit. (but it got some extra downvotes recently because of the meta effect here. To be fair there's nothing wrong with the **second** question judging by itself, and down voting to "punish" the author is not a valid strategy) -- that having said the policy is to **[close the older question as duplicate of the newer, if the newer is better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and)**.

Comment: @SecurityHound That yellow "possible spam" banner *can* appear (organically) on otherwise 'perfectly valid' questions. IIRC, it is shown when the source IP address of the post has been associated with earlier spam. (But mostly it shows on audits.)

Comment: @AdrianMole - That’s my point. It appeared on a perfectly valid question thus it had to be an audit

Comment: @SecurityHound But you seem to have missed *my* point. If the source IP of a perfectly valid question had previously been used for a post (or posts?) identified as spam, then you'll also see that yellow banner ... on an otherwise perfectly fine post. I've seen it quite a few times on decent posts that were *not* audits.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221680/616624) to how that banner works (or is *supposed* to work).

Comment: @AdrianMole - We are saying the same thing, the banner while performing reviews, is an indication it’s an audit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as the post and your review of it are concerned, I think you did the right thing – you spotted that the question was a duplicate (actually, a re-post by the same user) and acted accordingly by flagging it as a duplicate. Although, as mentioned in the comments, it *may* have been better to close the older question as the duplicate (as has now been done).

However (as you have now discovered), the review queue audit system is not without fault! There are numerous posts on Meta.SO and Meta.SE about this ([here's an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/616624)) and, despite much complaining by reviewers since (essentially) the review queues were first implemented, nothing has been done to improve the way audits are selected, and nor are there any plans to do so.

I can only offer a 'tip' as to how you can avoid failing such audits in the future: In this case, it appears that you were presented with the yellow banner stating:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

More often than not, this banner is an indicator that the review is an audit; opening up the post in its own window (i.e. outside the review queue) will generally reveal the fact that it is an audit: typically, the number of upvotes will be larger than in the review (for a "known good" audit), or the post will show as deleted (for a "known bad"). Though I wouldn't necessarily recommend opening up *all* reviews in their own windows, in cases where the system *explicitly* asks you to "review carefully," I think you should do so.

So, back to this particular case: This *may very well* be a bug in the system because the comment by Ted Lyngmo on the question strongly suggests that he had cast a close vote; I'm not a moderator so I can't confirm this, but the timeline shows that the post *was* submitted to the Close Vote review queue (but that it was invalidated – not sure how or why). Further, IIRC, posts that have had close votes cast on them (whether or not they were ultimately closed) should not be selected as "known good" audits.

In summary, all I would say is: Please keep up your good work in the review queues and don't be (too) disheartened by occasionally failing bad audits.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, I'm not dishartened and raised this mostly for the meta effect to get one of the posts closed as duplicate to remove this specific bad audit. I'll definitely keep chipping away these queues.